# How to add a long textfield in Matrix Module ?

Tags: 7

Does anyone know how to add a long text to the [matrix module](https://drupal.org/project/matrix) column?

I've tried with the "custom" field but it's not working.
Any idea?

Comment: Surely the [Morpheus module](https://drupal.org/project/morpheus) will be able to tame the Matrix module? (sorry I know that's not helpful, just couldn't resist :P)

Comment: @Clive - I never knew this module, thanks for putting name :)